# Rows selection based on the groups and ID match within group

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

I am trying to select rows based on the value from another group. Here is the dummy data frame

```
das <- data.frame(weigh=c(10,30,15,11,14,50,30,32,34,60,17,31,2,6,66,5,4,20,21,12,8,56,6,19),
                  id =c(123,124,125,126,127,128,1223,1224,1226,1225,1227,1228,123,124,125,126,127,128,1223,1224,1225,1226,1227,1228),
                  label=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                  category=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3))
```

I did the group by category and label and then pick the row that is of maximum weight. Which I  did like this.

```
das %>% group_by(category,label) %>% slice(which.max(weigh))
```

But what I am trying to do is to capture the rows with the id value from the same label within the other category. So the expected output in this dummy example be like this

```
weigh   id label category
50  128     A        1
15  125     A        1
60 1225     B        1
34 1226     B        1
66  125     A        3
20  128     A        3
56 1226     B        3
8 1225     B        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to join the data back to original data by `id` :

```
library(dplyr)

das %>% 
  group_by(category,label) %>% 
  slice(which.max(weigh)) %>%
  left_join(das, by = 'id') %>%
  select(weigh = weigh.y, id, category = category.y, label = label.y) %>%
  arrange(category, label)

#  weigh    id category label
#  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
#1    50   128        1 A    
#2    15   125        1 A    
#3    60  1225        1 B    
#4    34  1226        1 B    
#5    20   128        3 A    
#6    66   125        3 A    
#7     8  1225        3 B    
#8    56  1226        3 B
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this without joining

```
library(dplyr)
das %>%
   group_by(category, label) %>% 
   mutate(flag = weigh == max(weigh)) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(any(flag)) %>%
   select(-flag)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   id [4]
#  weigh    id label category
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#1    15   125 A            1
#2    50   128 A            1
#3    34  1226 B            1
#4    60  1225 B            1
#5    66   125 A            3
#6    20   128 A            3
#7     8  1225 B            3
#8    56  1226 B            3
```